# Anonymous parameters working- but not explicit ones - for scala reduceLeft

Tags: scala, reduce

Given a simple sequence:

```
scala> val a = Seq(1.0,2.0,3.0)
res8: Seq[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Let us add them up!

```
scala> a.reduceLeft{_ + _}
res6: Double = 6.0
```

But how to be explicit with the parameters? Here is my attempt:

```
scala> a.reduceLeft{case(b,c) =>   b+c}
```

Well .. *no* ..  We have a type mismatch:

```
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function

The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, Double) => ?
              a.reduceLeft{case(b,c) =>   b+c}
                          ^
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
              a.reduceLeft{case(b,c) =>   b+c
```

But even when I add in the types explicitly it does not work:

```
scala> a.reduceLeft{case(b:Double,c:Double) =>   b+c}

<console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, Double) => ?
              a.reduceLeft{case(b:Double,c:Double) =>   b+c}
```

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reduceLeft` takes a `Function2` not a `Function1` with a tuple input parameter.  Thus, you don't need to use `case` to pattern match; you just need to name your two input arguments.

The error message is not particularly helpful here, unfortunately, as it does say what it is missing but not in a way that really clearly instructs you on why what you're doing is not right.

Use `a.reduceLeft( (a,b) => a + b )`.  (Braces are fine too.)

Comment: thanks. I will award soon enough (looks like clock says 5 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote here:

`a.reduceLeft{case(b,c) =>   b+c}`

Is a partial function.

Let's take a look at the type signature of reduce left:

`def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B`

We can see it takes a higher order function `op` that takes two parameters, one of type `B`, the other of type `A`, and returns a `B`.

In this case we pass `op` as an anonymous function like so:

`a.reduceLeft((a, b) => a + b)`

Comment: Your explanation is also helpful: i awarded to RexKerr but have upvoted yours.